# Pasting values from fixed ranges across all worksheets onto one sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have about 30 worksheets (days of the month) and on each sheet

I would like to copy the values in ranges `A293:AL293` AND `A296:AL296` on each worksheet to my active sheet (in consecutive rows from 1st-30th of the month for example).

These ranges use the  `MIN` and `PERCENTILE` formula respectively. However, when i run the macro, the cells contain the !REF error as the formulae are copied instead of the actual cell values.

How should I modify the macro such that it will copy and paste values instead of formula?

The code that i modified from another macro that i used to copy and paste the data from 30 sheets into one sheet is:

```
Sub test()
Dim curRow As Integer
Dim activeWorksheet As Worksheet
Set activeWorksheet = ActiveSheet
curRow = 1
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Not ws.Name = activeWorksheet.Name Then
        ws.Range("A293:AL293").Copy Destination:=activeWorksheet.Range(CStr(curRow) & ":" & CStr(curRow + 288))
     curRow = curRow + 289   
    End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

Another code i found was:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CreateTempPSDReport()
Dim WS As Worksheet, Rept As Worksheet

Set Rept = Sheets("Temporary PSD Report")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'--> Loop through each worksheet except the report and
'--> Copy the set range to the report
For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Not WS.Name = "Temporary PSD Report" Then
        WS.Range("A42", "I42").Rows.Copy
        Rept.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial _
        Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

But I am uncertain what the

```
        WS.Range("A42", "I42").Rows.Copy
        Rept.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial _
        Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

portion does.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy the the pair of rows to a summary sheet you could do this. Two points to note

- The value rather than the formula is copied using `.Value`. In this case I used `.Value2`
- You don't need to copy and paste (unless you want to copy formats), you can simply set one range equal to the values in another

  ```
  Sub test()
  Dim ws1 As Worksheet
  Dim ws2 As Worksheet
  Dim lngCnt As Long

  Set ws1 = ActiveSheet
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  For Each ws2 In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
      If Not ws1.Name = ws2.Name Then
          ws1.[a1].Offset(lngCnt, 0).Resize(1, 38).Value2 = ws2.Range("A293:AL293").Value2
          ws1.[a1].Offset(lngCnt + 1, 0).Resize(1, 38).Value2 = ws2.Range("A296:AL296").Value2
          lngCnt = lngnct + 2
      End If
  Next ws2
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: thanks brettdj! actually, if i wanted to do the PERCENTILE function in A296:AL296 of every worksheet, can i use the above macro to achieve the same thing?